# The importance of stationarity for the oracle property of Elastic Net Regression?

Tags: machine-learning, lasso, stationarity, elastic-net, oracle

I've been on the lookout for a while, but unfortunately, I'm still coming up empty-handed in my search for papers or books that dive into the theoretical derivation or simulation of the impact of non-stationarity on elastic net regressions. Has anyone stumbled upon resources discussing this specific topic? Any pointers to relevant papers or books would be much appreciated!

Comment: Can you tell us a little bit more about what you mean when you say stationarity?

Comment: Certainly. I mean the concept of covariance-stationarity that assumes that the time series employed in variable selection possess a constant and unchanging mean, variance, and autocorrelation, making them mean-reverting.

Comment: Do you have any references for the stationary case?

Comment: Yes, here for example Masini, R. P., Medeiros, M. C., & Mendes, E. F. (2023). Machine learning advances for time series forecasting. Journal of economic surveys, 37(1), 76-111 the assumption is explicitly made on page 3 @Richard Hardy